# Custom/better magento product landing pages

Tags: magento

I tried and searched through some Stackoverflow question and answers but still wasn't able to find my answer. I am hoping this is something simple, but it not I'll give it a try either way. Is there an extension or can I setup product landing pages similar to this in magento? They look really nice and would like to do something similar on my magento site.

Example here: http://gearx.com/snow-sports

Any help or guidance would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a Magento store, so yes. Have you looked into creating your own themes at all? Here's a basic overview: http://fishpig.co.uk/blog/create-a-custom-theme-in-magento.html

Comment: Yeah, it seems like I'll have to copy the view.phtml and modify that file and then call it out in the custom design tab of the categories. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I was looking for: http://www.demacmedia.com/ecommerce/mini-tutorial-how-to-add-a-category-landing-page/

Now I am just trying to actually get it to work.